# What is the Grothendieck group of the category of $\mathbf{Z}_p[G]$-modules?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a suitably large finite extension of the $p$-adic integers, with residue field $\mathbf{F}_q$.

The Grothendieck group of the category of finitely-generated $\mathbf{F}_q[G]$-modules is naturally identified with a group of $\mathbf{C}$-valued functions on the set of conjugacy classes of elements of $G$ of order prime to $p$, via Brauer characters.

What is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated $\mathcal{O}[G]$-modules?

Comment: I've added a tag, since you assume $G$ is finite.   Note that the irreducible $p$-adic representations of an arbitrary $G$ are poorly understood, so it's not clear how far the full Grothendieck group can be characterized.   Also, the standard texts of Serre and Curtis-Reiner emphasize (following Brauer) the "intermediate" role of the Grothendieck group of f.g. *projective* modules instead: projectives for $\mathbb{F}_q [G]$ lift nicely to projective $\mathcal{O}[G]$-modules.   What is your motivation?

Comment: Note that surprinsingly many modules are zero in the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{O}[G]$ because of exakt sequences like $0 \to M \xrightarrow{p} M \to M/pM \to 0$ for any $M$ which is free as an $\mathcal{O}$-module. In particular: The projective $\mathbb{F}_q[G]$-modules (considered via the canonical map as $\mathcal{O}[G]$-modules) are zero in the Grothendieck group because they lift to projective and hence torsionfree $\mathcal{O}[G]$-modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it is isomorphic to the group of ordinary (virtual) characters over $K=\mbox{Frac}(\mathcal{O})$, the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}$.  That is, the Grothendieck group of $KG$.  An isomorphism is given by simply tensoring with $K$, so that $\mathcal{O}G$-modules $M,N$ are identified in $K_0(\mathcal{O}G)$ if and only if $K\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}M$ and $K\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}N$ afford the same character.  In particular, all torsion modules are zero in the Grothendieck group.

This was proved by Swan in 'The Grothendieck ring of a finite group', Topology 2, 85-110, 1963.  He proves a more general result over an arbitrary integral domain there, and Theorem 3 is the one you're after.